# Regex matches exact string contains word

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to "catch" the next path to do some action on it:

```
/root/m/api/users/<user-id-can be any combination of characters and digits>/content
```

The path must ends with `content`

For example:

```
/root/m/api/users/acme/content
```

To do so, I need to match regex to know if this the correct path:

```
private boolean isPathAllow(final String urlToBlock) {
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^/root/m/api/users/.*/content$").matcher(urlToBlock);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```

But it's return true even on requests like:

```
/root/m/api/users/acme/applications/versions/1.0/content
```

So I must do something wrong in the matches function.
Any help to do so as it's supposed to be?

Comment: `.*` is your problem. You need to only match the user-id until the next `/`

Comment: Use `\\w*` or `[-.\\w]*` or `[^/]+` instead of `.*`

Comment: Do you intend to match only paths which start with `/rootm/api/users/`, or is the only requirement that the path end with `content`?  In any case, why is your second example path not a match?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, it must starts with /root/m/api/users/ and end with content and must have user-id between those parts

Comment: Use `"^/root/m/api/users/[^/]+/content$"`

Comment: From your post "any combination of characters and digits" What are you referring to when you are saying characters? Did you mean alphabets and digits? If yes then you should use `^/root/m/api/users/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/content$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded with:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^/root/m/api/users/\\w*/content$").matcher(urlToBlock);
```

or

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("^/root/m/api/users/[^/]+/content$").matcher(urlToBlock);
```

So what are the differents between them (`\\w*` vs `[^/]+`)?

Comment: It's all explained in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: `\w` does not match `-`, it only matches what `[A-Za-z0-9_]` matches. `[^/]` matches any char other than `/`.

Comment: Take care, because if an element name can contains dot like "1.0" as there is an example before, the (\w*) will not match with the special charactered names.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is [greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) so it takes everything between `users/` and `/content`.

Use `[^/]` to catch everything that is not `/` between `users/` and `/content`. Or you can make the `.*` [lazy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) by appending a question mark (`?`).

A 'greedy' quantifier will try to match as much tokens possible. A 'lazy' quantifier will stop at the first mach.
In some cases, greedy quantifiers can also be much less efficient, as the regex engine will try to match more (or a lot more) tokens after the actual good match. And will back trace only after a certain failure.